# Conditional when in less-file

Tags: less

I am making a theme editor for WordPress, and would like to use less to build the CSS file.

I have put a string in a variable like this:

```
@banner-separation-style: 'thick_border';
```

Then I'm trying to use when() like this:

```
when (@banner-separation-style = 'thick_border') {
    header {
        ... some style
    }
    ... and some css selectors
}
```

I've also tried combinations without quoting the variable.

How do I properly create something similar to if-blocks with less?

Comment: The answer below, and do not please use quotes when not necessary - just `thick_border` (not `'thick_border'`) would be enough (And`thick-border` is even better counting the style of your variable naming).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guards (`when` statement) can only be used along with a [mixin](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature) or a [CSS selector](http://lesscss.org/features/#css-guards-feature). We can't write a `when` statement without using one of those. So, either write it with a mixin like below:

```css
@banner-separation-style: 'thick_border';
.border-styles() when (@banner-separation-style = 'thick_border') {
    header { border: 2px solid red; }
    nav { border: 2px solid green; }
}
.border-styles;
```

or directly with the CSS selector like below:

```css
@banner-separation-style: 'thick_border';
header when (@banner-separation-style = 'thick_border') {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
nav when (@banner-separation-style = 'thick_border') {
    border: 2px solid green;
}
```

or atleast using an unnamed selector (`&`) like below:

```css
@banner-separation-style: 'thick_border';
& when (@banner-separation-style = 'thick_border') {
  header { border: 2px solid red; }
  nav { border: 2px solid green; }
}
```

The first version (with mixin) is the one that I prefer because (a) you don't have to repeat the condition multiple times like in the CSS selector version and (b) giving the mixin a name makes it more readable than using an unnamed selector. It is just my choice and some other user could actually prefer the last because it doesn't need that extra mixin call statement.

Comment: The mixin worked. I tried the version "header when ..." before asking, but it did not work. Tried it again now and it still does not work. Also tried `body when (...) {
    header {}
}´. Might be my less-compiler.

Comment: @frodeborli: The CSS + guard option was only introduced in a later version of the compiler (v1.6 if I remember right), is your compiler up to date (or) are you using some other port of Less.js like dotLess, LessPHP etc? Those maybe the reason.